# How to show webpage message only without browser message in mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, browser

I want to show custom message when user is about to leave a page for that I have written below code

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Are you sure you want to close";
}
```

Its working but it also gives browser message, which is not required.
Browser message is like Leave this page or stay on this page with header "Are you sure you want to leave".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change that message or the button labels. Browsers implement it that way to protect the user from malicious websites.

Think about what would happen if you could.

- If the message box were entirely optional, you could create popup ads and prevent the user from closing the window at all
- You could make the message something like "Do you want to delete all data on your computer?", thus ensuring that the user always clicks "no" and tells the browser to stay on the page.